# Select from table identified by OID

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to select from a table I know the OID of? Something like

```
select * from 123456::regclass
```

I understand I can do it in a function, by constructing a dynamic query, but it seems strange I cannot do it directly -- I would assume Postgresql translates all my table names to OIDs the moment it starts analyzing my query, so why cannot I save it the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

OID is a global counter which can *wrap around*. Meaning there can be multiple tables containing objects of same OID. So even if there was some hack around, it would error prone in the least